# Jquery validation before form submits to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms

I have tried and tried with this and don't seem to be getting anywhere, so thought I would put it out there. I have a form full of data provided by the user that I have thus far been able to validate with js/jQuery without problem before sending it to php for further processing. I am achieving this like so:

```
form.submit(function(){  
            if(validateUserName() & validateEmail1() & validateEmail2() & validatePass1() & validatePass2() & acceptTerms()){
                return true;
            } else  {
                return false;  
            }
        });
```

The form itself uses the following attributes:

```
<form id="signup" action="registration.php" method="post">
```

The problem function is `acceptTerms()`, which simply has to check that a checkbox is selected does not seem to work as it should (or as the rest of the validation functions do).

```
    var termscons = $('input:checkbox[name=termscons]');

    termscons.change(acceptTerms);

    function acceptTerms(){
        if($(termscons).is(':checked')) {

            termsconsInfo.text("");
            return true;
        } else {
            termsconsInfo.text("In order to join, you must accept these terms and conditions.");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I have integrated the `termscons.change` listener and `termsconsInfo.text("");` to ensure that my selectors are pointing at the right thing, and that the function is being fired correctly (which it appears to, by changing the `termsconsInfo.text` when its state changes). When I try to submit the form however it appears to return false, since it does not submit. It should in fact be returning true, and posting my form over to my php script.

Am I going about this the right way? Is there something I have been missing when dealing with a checkbox as opposed to a textinput?

Please excuse my ignorance, this is all still very new to me.

Comment: you can try with attributes like this: if($("input:checkbox[name=termscons]").attr("checked") == "checked")

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you are using `&` in your if statement. It needs to be `&&`.

Second problem is with `acceptTerms` (as you guessed):

```
var termscons = $('input:checkbox[name=termscons]');

termscons.change(acceptTerms);

function acceptTerms(){
    if(termscons.is(':checked')) {      // <-- termscons is already a jQuery object

        termsconsInfo.text("");
        return true;
    } else {
        termsconsInfo.text("In order to join, you must accept these terms and conditions.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

There might be more, but that is what I see for now.

Answer (score 0):

i say forget reinventing the wheel and use something already tested for instance [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)